# Java console read input line by line and store in String array

Tags: java, string

I have a question regarding reading strings from java console. When I give input of words each line until I stop with "stop" All those words should be stored in one array of string.

My input will be:

> apple
>   Mango
>   grapes
>   stop -----> on stop the string ends here

All the 3 fruit names will be stored in `temp`.

But when I type one word and want to type another by clicking enter to go to next line, it prints the output.

How should I modify this?

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the words");
String temp=scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: statue :) 
put scanner.nextLine() into a while loop and exit only on particular word of your choice like okstop :)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're reading one line from console and print it.

What you should do is keep reading lines until "stop", and that could be done by having a while loop.

This code should work well for you:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the words");
String input = scanner.nextLine(); // variable to store every input line
String fruits = "";        // this should store all the inputs in one string
while(! input.equals("stop")) {
     fruits += input + ",";  // using comma to separate the inputs  
     input = scanner.nextLine();
}
String[] res = fruits.split(","); // splitting the string to have its content in an array
```

Comment: Hi.,  Thank you very much I used the while part alone from your code. Now its working for me.